# PHP Minifier Plugin

Tags: plugins, netbeans-plugins

I a, using code minimiser with net-beans since long time. Though I am succeeded with finding it for JS & CSS plug-ins. but few days back When I google for PHP Minimizer to protect whole of my code I came across this link `http://customhost.com.ua/php-minify/` Is their any other plug-in or any other source to implement this to net-beans so I can minify and protect my code through single click. Is their any plug-in in development or already developed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think minify `php` will work

### PHP is a server-side scripting language

so when it comes to client side it will displayed in `html`

you can't inspect php code both locally and hosted so what is need of minify `php`

as you mentioned above php minify

### minify this

```
<?php
//process login form if submitted

    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');

    echo         $username;
         echo $password;
?>
```

### **minifyed**

```
<?php
$username=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'username');$password=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'password');echo $username;echo $password;?>
```

even after minify above `php` code will just display *username* and *password*